# The query performance is very low + correlated subquery

Tags: oracle11g

The query's aim is to get reserved rooms status is 3 or going to reserve in 30 to 45 minutes  status in 2 or unreserved status in 1. reservation rooms are in RESEENH table and each reservation is in ORD_NOARCHIVE table which has begintime and endtime of reservation. So for each reservation room this query checks whether reservation is available at current time also its checks the meeting room parents and children. if children is reserved then parents are are blocked.
it takes 10 secs to fetch first 50 records.

```
with cte as 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT R.syscode, 
                R.behcode,                
                R.syscode AS FK_RESERVATIONUNIT, ( 
                CASE 
                                WHEN R.TYPE = 3 THEN '1' 
                                WHEN R.TYPE = 1 THEN '2' 
                                ELSE NULL 
                END )                               AS LOCATION_TYPE, 
                R.sysobjalg                         AS FK_PROPERTY, 

                MP.syscode                          AS FK_MEASUREMENTPOINT, 
                MP.fk_plc_occupancy_state           AS FK_PLC_OCCUPANCY_STATE, 
                F.syscode                           AS FK_FLOOR,
                R.transitiontime,
                r.type,
                r.is_compoundreservationunit,
                r.is_archived,
                MP.fk_person,
                os.transitionperiod
FROM            reseenh R 
--left outer join ordtrantbl RSS 
--ON              RSS.reservationunisyscode = R.syscode 
left outer join objond F 
ON              F.syscode = R.fk_floor 
left outer join pln_measurementpoint MP 
ON              MP.fk_reservationunit = R.syscode 
AND             MP.is_primary_measurement_point = 'T',
pln_ordersetting os 

)
select cte.syscode,cte.behcode,cte.FK_RESERVATIONUNIT,
 (CASE 
                                WHEN O.begindatetime_user IS NULL THEN '1'                                                                 --GREEN 
                                WHEN O.begindatetime_user - (Nvl(cte.transitiontime, ( cte.transitionperiod ))/1440 ) > current_date THEN '2'  -- ORANGE 
                                WHEN O.begindatetime_user + (Nvl(cte.transitiontime, ( cte.transitionperiod )) /1440 ) > current_date THEN '3' -- RED 
                                ELSE '3' 
                END )     AS LOCAVAILABILITY_STATUS_CODE, 
                cte.LOCATION_TYPE,                
                cte.FK_PROPERTY,
                 Coalesce(O.sysmelder, cte.fk_person) AS FK_PERSON, 
                O.syscode                           AS FK_ORDER, 
                O.ref_bostate_userdefined           AS FK_ORDER_STATE_USER, 
                O.fk_bostate                        AS FK_ORDER_STATE_SYSTEM,
                FK_MEASUREMENTPOINT,FK_PLC_OCCUPANCY_STATE,FK_FLOOR
from cte left outer join ord_noarchive O on O.syscode in 
( SELECT MAX(ord.syscode) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ord.begindatetime_user) OVER (PARTITION BY ord.sysreseenh )
                       FROM   ord_noarchive ORD 


                       WHERE  ( ( ( 
                                                   current_date >= ( ORD.begindatetime_user - ( Nvl(cte.transitiontime, ( cte.transitionperiod ))/1440) )
                                            AND    ( 
                                                          current_date - ( Nvl(cte.transitiontime, (cte.transitionperiod )) / 1440 ) ) <=ORD.enddatetime_user )
                                     OR     ( ( 
                                                          current_date + ( ( 
                                                          CASE 
                                                                 WHEN ( 
                                                                               cte.TYPE = 1 ) THEN 30
                                                                 ELSE 45 
                                                          END ) / 1440 ) ) >= ( ORD.begindatetime_user - (Nvl(cte.transitiontime, ( cte.transitionperiod))/1440 ) )
                                            AND    ( 
                                                          current_date - ( Nvl(cte.transitiontime, ( cte.transitionperiod )) / 1440 ) ) < ORD.enddatetime_user ) )
                              AND    ORD.sysreseenh IN 
                                     ( 
                                            SELECT fk_reservationunit_parent 
                                            FROM   pln_reservationunit_rut 
                                            WHERE  fk_reservationunit_child IN 
                                                   ( 
                                                          SELECT fk_reservationunit_child 
                                                          FROM   pln_reservationunit_rut 
                                                          WHERE  cte.is_compoundreservationunit = 'T'
                                                          AND    fk_reservationunit_parent = cte.syscode)
                                            UNION 
                                            SELECT cte.syscode 
                                            FROM   dual 
                                            UNION 
                                            SELECT 
                                                   CASE 
                                                          WHEN cte.is_compoundreservationunit = 'T' THEN fk_reservationunit_child
                                                          ELSE fk_reservationunit_parent 
                                                   END 
                                            FROM   pln_reservationunit_rut 
                                            WHERE  ( 
                                                          cte.is_compoundreservationunit = 'T' 
                                                   AND    fk_reservationunit_parent = cte.syscode )
                                            OR     ( 
                                                          cte.is_compoundreservationunit = 'F' 
                                                   AND    fk_reservationunit_child = cte.syscode ))
                              AND    ORD.fk_bostate IN 
                                     ( 
                                            SELECT syscode 
                                            FROM   pln_bostate 
                                            WHERE  pnname IN ( 'Requested', 
                                                              'Made', 
                                                              'AdministrativelyCompleted' ) 
                                            AND    fk_bodefinition = ref_bodefinition) 

                              AND    ORD.sysreseenh = O.sysreseenh                                
                              ))
 WHERE           cte.is_archived = 'F' 
AND             cte.TYPE IN ( 1, 
                           3 )  
                       AND             cte.fk_floor=495
```

Comment: standard "speed up the query" advice: put indexes on ALL fields use in a "decision" context: `where`, `join`, `case`, etc...

Comment: but if you have millions of rows, index worth nothing...

Comment: anyway, first you have to tell us how many rows r in that tables, and give us explain plan too

Comment: RESEENH Table have 1000 rows, ORD_NOARCHIVE might have 3 to 5 million records.

Answer (score 0):

No time to analyze the details of a very complex query, but my overall sense is that you are trying to do too many things at once.  Separate the tasks.  Check on room availability in one query, and check on the children/parent thing in a separate query.

Also, you could analyze the execution plan for the query and see what it bogging it down.  My suspicion (again without time to really try to understand your query)  is that at some point the mixing of tasks is translating into a many-to-many relationship where you have an intermediate result that is a cross product of rows between some of the tables in your query.

Comment: Hi Marc & Gilchirst,

Thanks for your answers. I will try to take up your suggestions. I have already indexed most of the stuff. 

@Gilchirst: you are almost true by saying many to many relation. What happens is at current time I look into ORD_NOARCHIVE table to check any matching records along with their parent child relationship in table pln_reservationunit_rut. For eg:
A is parent and B and c are childs then..

Case 1:
 If C is booked then I should show A is also booked but not B. 

Case 2:
If A is booked then B and C are also booked.